# Mac Mail not archiving messages and not closing

Tags: mail.app

Ever since I updated to OS 10.13.1, my mail app has not been archiving my messages. It shows the message as archived, until I close and reopen, then all my messages that were archived come back. Also, when I hit close, the icon just stays there (doesn't say not responding), and I have to hit option-cmd-escape to close it.